# How do I include DTO schemas that are only referenced using `$ref`?

Tags: nestjs, swagger

In order to allow for reusage as well as keeping my DTO objects to a managable size, I have some DTOs that are only used as part of another DTO in the form of a `$ref` reference. This happens most frequently, when using a dictionary with DTO properties:

```js
export class PriceSuggestionDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: { $ref: getSchemaPath(PriceDto) },
  })
  conditionPrices: Record<string, PriceDto>;
}
```

When viewing the generated Swagger documentation, the type of the property is `Record<string, string>`and there is an error message at the top of the page.

```
Resolver error at paths./price-suggestions.get.responses.200.content.application/json.schema.items.properties.conditionPrices.properties.$ref
Could not resolve reference: Could not resolve pointer: /components/schemas/PriceDto does not exist in document
```

Is it possible to force NestJS to include the specified DTO into swagger's schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ApiExtraModels` decorator to include DTOs that are not directly part of any requests or responses. You can add this anywhere, but it probably makes most sense above the DTO that references the `$ref`:

```js
@ApiExtraModels(PriceDto)
export class PriceSuggestionDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: { $ref: getSchemaPath(PriceDto) },
  })
  conditionPrices: Record<string, PriceDto>;
}
```

Adding it once is enough to include it in swagger. Though adding it above every model that references the DTO is more consistent and will help you when refactoring models.

You can also add it using the `extraModels` property when generating the swagger document:

```js
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options, {
  extraModels: [PriceDto],
});
```

> Source: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/types-and-parameters#extra-models